# How to change the value of a variable using input field?

Tags: php, user-meta, variables, users

I have created a wordpress website. I want to extract each user's data using php through his/her id.

I have created this code;

```
<?php
$userid = /* help me get the below input field's value */
$user_info = get_userdata($userId);
      echo 'Username: ' . $user_info->user_login . "\n";
      echo 'User roles: ' . implode(', ', $user_info->roles) . "\n";
      echo 'User ID: ' . $user_info->ID . "\n";
    ?>
<input name="getUser" id="getUser" value=''/>
```

The user will write the id of the user he wants to extract his data. and then the data will echo back.

The code is working fine but i can't set the value of "**getUser**" input field to "**$userId**" variable. Also i want that php to re-execute on input field value change.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below snippet of code.

**HTML :**

```
<input name="getUser" id="getUser" value=''/>
<div id="user_data"></div>
```

**JS (js/my-ajax-script.js)**

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#getUser').keyup(function(e) {
      var user_id = e.target.value;
      console.log(user_id);
      $.ajax({
            url:my_ajax_object.ajaxurl, #add here your ajax url
            type:'POST',
             data:'action=get_this_user_data&user_id='+user_id ,
             success:function(results)
             {
              jQuery('#user_data').html(results);

             }
        });
    });
});
```

**Ajax (add in functions.php)**

```
function my_enqueue() {

wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my-ajax-script.js', array('jquery') );

wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'my_ajax_object',
        array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
   }
   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );

add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_this_user_data', 'get_this_user_data' );
add_filter( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_this_user_data', 'get_this_user_data');
function get_this_user_data()
{
    $userid = $_POST["user_id"];
    $data = '';
    $user_info = get_userdata($userid);
     if(!empty($user_info))
     {
       $data .= '<pre>';
       $data .= 'Username: ' . $user_info->user_login . '<br/>';
       $data .= 'User roles: ' . implode(', ', $user_info->roles) . '<br/>';
       $data .= 'User ID: ' . $user_info->ID . '<br/>';
       $data .='</pre>';
     }
     else
     {
        $data = "user data not found";
     }

      echo $data;
      die();
}
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: sorry, i'm newbie in the wordpress backend. I pasted the ajax code to the functions.php file and i change the url to my url  = (wordpress\78-5) . Also i added the html code. After doing all this stuff, the input is not extracting data to the #userData div. Please can you figure out why?

Comment: I have updated code in my answer. please check now.  i have added ajax url and create js file separated and enqueue in functions.php. let me know if any issue.

Comment: Can you please explain to me how i can add my ajax url? if i'm not wrong i made it like this ( url : '/wordpress/78-2',). Still the form is not working.

Comment: yes your are wrong. i have already added ajax url. you have to just create new **my-ajax-script.js** file in js folder. then add other code in functions.php file. i have already added ajax url **my_ajax_object.ajaxurl** in js function. you dont need to change now. just add in files and see it is working or not.

Comment: i copied your code exactly to the above files without changing anything, it doesn't work. sorry for my ignorance towards ajax.

Comment: what kind of issue you are facing ? did you get any kind or errors in console ? where did you added a above code ?

Comment: I added your code without edits 1. ajax code to \wp-includes\js\my-ajax-script.js.  2. php code to \wp-includes\functions.php. and the html code to my html page. I was getting errors.          Now i switched that code to 1. php code to /wp-content/themes/twentynineteen/functions.php 2. Ajax code to /wp-content/themes/twentynineteen/js/my-ajax-script.js .   Now in the console i'm getting this error in the ajax page 'SyntaxError: fields are not currently supported'.Please help...

Comment: You must never modify  /wp-includes/ folder files because it is WordPress core files.  1. all php code and ajax code goes to functions.php file 2. you have to create  my-ajax-script.js named js file in themes js folder and add js code into this file.

Comment: i did so, but the code is not working. I'm getting this error 'SyntaxError: fields are not currently supported' in the frontEnd.